# PHP script crashes on ö/é

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and use a php script to get all rows and values from the database and output them in a json file. It works fine as long as there are no special characters in it. ' \ and / and so on work perfectly, only ö,ä or û and so on break it and nothing happens. Whats the problem?

```
<?php

$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["arr"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $arr = array();
        $arr["id"] = $row["id"];
        $arr["version"] = $row["version"];
        $arr["info"] = $row["info"];

        // push single info into final response array
        array_push($response["arr"], $arr);
    }

    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Nothing found";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer. Otherwise in the forum it looks like your question is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Original poster found solution and posted it in question. I edited and post it here so that the topic can be closed.*)

FOUND THE SOLUTION:

```
Add this to the PHP file:

if (!mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn)) {
    echo "Error: Unable to set the character set.\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: When you post someone elses answer you should mark your answer as "community wiki".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, like following :

```
echo json_encode($reponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Ref : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/json.constants.php